# Windows 7 desktop icons view to Medium returb back to List | Why?

Tags: windows-7, icons

I set all icons view to list and apply it on Folder options view.
Now i want to change desktop icons view to medium - Not other places.
The problem is after change desktop icons view to medium it returns back list after a while and this is so annoying.
How can i keep desktop icons view to Medium?

Comment: Windows Explorer (Windows 7 and up to Windows 10) is not that flexible.  It you need folder by folder views that differ, you need a third party Explorer that can do this. I use xPorer2 and I think you may be able to use Advanced options in xPlorer2 to accommodate this.

Comment: but this is not right

Comment: i want to change view of a folder - there should be a solution about that.

Comment: Windows Explorer will not keep document views via folder options the same over time - never has for me.

Comment: is it possible to create an ini file for that folder? can this help?

Comment: I do not see here and have not seen before an INI file for Windows Explorer. Advanced options for third party apps, yes.

Comment: what is wrong about my question. who did dowvote me? these people make me upset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 is supposed to retain individual views for individual folders. However, over time, the settings underpinning this functionality tend to get corrupted.

See [KB813711 - Changes to the size, view, icon or position of a folder are lost (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328004952/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813711)

**SYMPTOMS**
The changes to the size, view, icon or position of a folder are lost on a computer that is running Windows XP, Windows Vista, or Windows 7.

**CAUSE**
This issue occurs because the registry settings for folder options are incorrect.

**RESOLUTION**

**Diagnose and fix the problem automatically**
The Diagnose and repair Windows File and Folder Problems automatically troubleshooter may automatically fix the problem described in this article.

**Fix the problem manually**
(Windows Vista or Windows 7)

```
Delete the following registry subkeys:
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags


For x64-based versions of Windows Vista or Windows 7, delete the following registry subkeys:
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
Re-create the following registry subkeys:
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags


For x64-based versions of Windows Vista or Windows 7, re-create the following registry subkeys:
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
Create and then set the BagMRU Size registry value to 5000 in the registry subkeys that you created in Step 2.
```

See also [Windows 10 forgets Folder View settings](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-7-forgets-folder-view-settings)